# Difference between cast types

Tags: c++, function, int

What exactly is the difference between these two:
both are ints
int x;

```
x(0)
```

and

```
int x = 0
```

Are they equivalent and if not why?

EDIT:

It's to deal with inheritance. You've got something looking like this:

```
class A{
protected:

int x;

public:

A() : x(0) {};
void show  {cout << "x" << x;     }



};



Class B {
protected:
int y;
public:
B()  {x = 0; y = 2; }

void show  {cout << "x" << x << "y" << y;    }


};
```

Is the `x(0)` legal? Please clarify.

Comment: I don't see any casts in here. `x(0)` isn't valid, though.

Comment: My appologize for the duplicate. Didnt see that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference, also in C++0X: `X{0}`

And technically they are not cast types, they are initialization or construction.

int x = 0 will call int(0) so it is a constructor call and not assignment.